# what is the meaning of "be stuck with someone something"?

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of be stuck with someone something in this sentence?
He has **stuck with me philosophy** and all.

Comment: It's really two separate phrases - "he has stuck with me" and "philosophy and all".

Answer (score 3):

That construction could mean something like "He has remained true and loyal to me, in spite of my philosophy and everything else about me which would be difficult for anyone to abide with".

But we'd need more context to be sure.

It would be punctuated:

He has stuck with me, philosophy and all.

Compare:  "She loves him, warts and all" where "warts" is used figuratively to mean "flaws in character, bad temperament, imperfections of some kind", not literally skin blemishes.

Comment: so nice. It's helpful.